# Clash of Clans Linked but not

Tags: clash-of-clans

My brother has an iPhone 5s and I have an iPod 4, we use the same gamecenter and apple ID. My brother plays clash of clans so I decided to make a new village on my iPod. I start up my new game (this is the first time downloading Clash of Clans on this device). When it loads up, it loads up my brother's village even though we never linked it. I then made a new Apple ID. After I deleted the game and downloaded it again, it still loads up my brother's village. I want a new village. How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 5):

Try this way :

1. Delete Clash of Clans from your device .
2. Log out from **Facebook** and **Game Center** from your device.
3. Restart your device.
4. Log in to your new game center account
5. Re-install Clash of Clans from App Store.
6. Launch Clash of Clans .

   If You get the pop-up asking that if you want to load your old village , click cancel.